# Finding the real error in a Webtest test failure

Tags: python, unit-testing, webtest

I'm using Python and Webtest to test a WSGI application.  I found that exceptions raised in the handler code tend to be swallowed by Webtest, which then raises a generic:

```
AppError: Bad response: 500 Internal Server Error
```

How do I tell it to raise or print the original error that caused this?

Comment: There will be `error` redirected to some file in WSGI config. You can check in that for getting error on some file.

Answer (score 6):

While clj's answer certainly works, you may still want to access the response in your test case. To do this, you can use `expect_errors=True` (from the [webtest documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/testapp.html#what-is-tested-by-default)) when you make your request to the TestApp, and that way no AppError will be raised. Here is an example where I am expecting a 403 error:

```
# attempt to access secure page without logging in
response = testapp.get('/secure_page_url', expect_errors=True)

# now you can assert an expected http code, 
# and print the response if the code doesn't match
self.assertEqual(403, response.status_int, msg=str(response))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was failing to catch the other exceptions in my tests until I saw this expect_errors arg.

Comment: and you can also use `status` keyword args: testapp.get('/secure_page_url', status=403)

Answer (score 4):

Your WSGI framework and server contains handlers which catch exceptions and performs some action (render a stacktrace in the body, log the backtrace to a logfile, etc). Webtest, by default, does not show the actual response, which might be useful if your framework renders a stacktrace in the body. I use the following extension to Webtest when I need to look at the body of the response:

```
class BetterTestApp(webtest.TestApp):

    """A testapp that prints the body when status does not match."""

    def _check_status(self, status, res):
        if status is not None and status != res.status_int:
            raise webtest.AppError(
                "Bad response: %s (not %s)\n%s", res.status, status, res)
        super(BetterTestApp, self)._check_status(status, res)
```

Getting more control over what happens to the exception depends on what framework and server you are using. For the built in `wsgiref` module you might be able to override [error_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.handlers.BaseHandler.error_output) to achieve what you want.